# Using Caption Filter Module with Media Module 2.x

Tags: 7, media

I'm seeking a good method for non-technically savvy users to easily caption images. [Caption Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/caption_filter) seems an excellent method to achieve this, however, even though this article says it is compatible with [Media 2.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/media), it doesn't seem to be.

Does anyone have experience with using this module that could fill me in on how to use them together?

Alternatively, **if anyone knows how to get Media 2.x to insert the actual `<img>` tag in the WYSIWYG**, rather than the bracketed content, that would solve the problem as well.

Comment: We don't use Media.module, but one easy method (if you don't need HTML'd captions with links etc) is just to use the "Title" or the "Alt" field's values. We extract the Title attribute's value from images with class `.caption` and add it back below the image as a paragraph. Quite easy for users, and no extra modules (Just a bit of jQuery).

Comment: That's a good idea @Beebee. There's a module (for those who might not be savvy with jQuery like myself) called [JCaption](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcaption) which does just that. It extracts the Title (or Alt value depending on your preference) and displays it below the image. I'm just seeing if I can get the Caption Filter module to work, first, because it has a nice default display of the caption and that's work we wouldn't have to do.